# Ruby on Rails 4 - Model to adjust Rails.configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, configuration

**UPDATED AGAIN**
I've modified the applicaiton to handle building a form for each setting entry.  The form posts to /Settings with a :put method and is looped in a transaction block.

Here is my code:

```
# settings_controller.rb
class SettingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @settings = Setting.all
  end

  def update
    Setting.transaction do
      params[:settings].each do |k, v|
        @setting = Setting.find(k)
        @setting.update(params.require(:settings)[k].permit(:value))
      end
    end
end

# settings/index.html.erb
<%= form_tag "/settings", :method => "put" do %>
    <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Setting</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
      <tbody>
    <% @settings.each  do |setting| %>
        <tr>
        <%= fields_for "settings[]", setting do |sf| %>
            <td><%= sf.label :name, t(setting.name) %></td>
            <td><%= sf.text_field :value %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <%= submit_tag("Save Changes") %>
    <%= link_to 'back', articles_path %>
<% end %>

#models/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true,
            length: { minimum: (Setting.find_by_name("validation_article_title_length_min").value.to_i) }
end
```

I don't think this is a good way to do this and here is why:
I had to jump through hoops to get the view to render each setting since it is part of multiple records.  I am using an i18n translation to translate the database name of "validation_article_title_length_min" to "Minimum Article Title Length"... I don't know if that is normal or not.

I can't validate each record in the model this way specific to what each setting may require.

And finally (and this is a big one) the article validation is not working. It will accept the value from the database and work as expected but upon changing the value via the form (and I verified the value did change), the validation sticks with the old number.  After some time passes it starts using thew new number.

There has got to be an easier way to do all of this?  Perhaps I should modify the migration so that each setting is its own column?  Doing that would fix my form and the transaction loop I have to do in my controller.
But at the end of the day the validation in article isn't changing with a database update and I do not know why.

Thanks again for guidance on this.

**UPDATED**
Thanks to comments by @Frederick Cheung, I believe it may be best to go with a database entry for settings.  Doing this poses two problems:
I want the settings index page to show all the settings and allow editing and posting from that page.

If I were to have 5 validation settings, clicking post should ensure all 5 were valid before posting a single one to the database.

Also, how would you recommend storing this in the database?  I've played around with the migration and I can either make each column a different application setting.  Or I can make each setting a row.

Thanks again for the help; I am hoping this all clicks soon.

**Previous Post:**

I have a brand new rails project with the "getting started" tutorial from the rails site.  Everything is working as expected.

**My Task:**
Currently users can add an article.  The article title must be > 5 characters.  I wanted to make this number an environment configuration variable.  Then, I wanted to be able to adjust this variable from the web page.

**What I've Done so far**
I created a settings resource.  I tried saving settings to the database as individual rows but this meant each setting could be edited only one at a time.  After googling I found that configuration variables could be created in `config/article_valdiation.yml`

```
default: &default
  title_length_min: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  bar: dev

test:
  <<: *default
  bar: test
```

Then in the `config/environment.rb` I did the following:

```
Rails.configuration.article = ActiveSupport::OrderedOptions.new()
Rails.configuration.article.validation = Rails.application.config_for(:article_validation).deep_symbolize_keys
```

I am trying to create a structure like Rails.configuration.element.configcatagory[config_element]

Here is the settings route and view.

```
# routes.rb
resources :settings do
    collection do
      put :update
      patch :update
    end
  end

# settings/index.html.erb
<% render plain: params[:setting].inspect %>
<h1>Application Settings</h1>
<%= form_tag("/settings", :method => "put") do %>
    <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Setting</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Minimum Article Title Length</td>
          <td><%= text_field_tag('article[:title_length_min]', Rails.configuration.article.validation[:title_length_min])  %></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <%= submit_tag("Save Changes") %>
    <%= link_to 'back', articles_path %>
<% end %>
```

**The Problem**
Perhaps I am configuring things incorrectly but...:

1. I can't determine how to setup the view so the params is sent to specify both "article", "validation" and "title_length_min".
2. I don't know how to make the control parse the params properly.  It gets the params but I don't know what to do with them since I can't do the usual Setting.find and Setting.update(params.require(:something, :somethingelse)
3. I feel like there should be a model to configure these custom configurations but I am at a loss on where to start to make that work.

Comment: I don't think this will work (for one, changes like this won't be persisted). I'd revisit the database approach

Comment: You have a point, I kinda forgot out the persistence issue... If I do the database approach, I can only post to 1 setting at a time.  Think of any config page of any application.  There are usually several options on the same page.  When you click save, all of these options are stored.  I'll update my question to reflect this new line of thinking.  Thank you.

Comment: Either editing multiple settings simultaneously or storing multiple settings in a single object should both be possible.

Comment: I probably had problems with this because of how I tried to create the migration.  I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something like this:

class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base

```
  validates_uniqueness_of :name

  def self.get_by_name(name)
    s = Setting.where(:name => name).first
    unless Setting.where(:name => name).first.nil?
      if s.values.nil?
        s.value
      else
        s.values
      end
    end
  end 

  def self.set_by_name(name, val)
    if val.kind_of?(Array)
      Setting.where(:name => name).first.update_attribute('values', val)
    else
      Setting.where(:name => name).first.update_attribute('value', val)
    end
  end

end
```

the call the settings int the view like:

```
<%= Setting.get_by_name('site_name') %>
```

Comment: That is helpful but how do you ensure that 5 settings being updated at the same time don't write the first 4 and fail the 5th?  Also, is your migration for the Setting table something like :name => 'string' :value => 'string'?

Comment: I would add a method to the settings class to accept the 5 parameters as a hash and wrap it in an ActiveSupport::Transaction so it succeeds on all of them or rolls back. I can post the migration if you are interested.

Comment: Yes that could work.  I am having alot of difficulty wrapping my head around how to do all of this.  I know all the principals but the syntax is throwing me off.  Any example code you can provide may get me going.  Thanks